# React: setState from imported image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sure I am way off base however I can't seem to resolve this problem.  I have imported two images that I want to swap out when my function is run by means of setting the state.  I can't seem to do that and am unsure what I'm missing (I am new to react coming from a UX designer background).

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import faceanni from '../../../static/faceanni.png';
import facedarth from '../../../static/facedarth.png';
import {Row, Col} from 'react-flexbox-grid';

const StarTitle = styled.h1`
  color: white;
`

class Kylo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      greetings: 'Dark Side',
      clickFor: 'Spanish',
      face: 'facedarth',
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.greetings == 'Dark Side') {
      this.setState({greetings: 'Light Side'});
      this.setState({clickFor: 'English'});
      this.setState({face: {facedarth}})
    } else {
      this.setState({greetings: 'Dark Side'})
      this.setState({clickFor: 'Wookie'})
      this.setState({face: 'faceanni'})
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrap">
        <div style={{marginTop: '2em', marginBottom: '5em', width: '80%'}}>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            <StarTitle>Coming soon!</StarTitle>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            <Row center="md">
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6}>
                <p>{this.state.greetings}</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>click for {this.state.clickFor}!</button>
                <img src={this.state.face} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Kylo;
```

So with `import facedarth from '../../../static/facedarth.png';` I am unsure how to utilize `{facedarth}` with state.  I may not even be making clear sense (I hope I am).  Can anyone tell me where I'm missing the mark?

Comment: Instead of putting facedarth in quotes ('') use them without quotes and curly braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `setState` directly to the imported image variable as

```
class Kylo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      greetings: 'Dark Side',
      clickFor: 'Spanish',
      face: facedarth,
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.greetings == 'Dark Side') {
      this.setState({greetings: 'Light Side'});
      this.setState({clickFor: 'English'});
      this.setState({face: facedarth})
    } else {
      this.setState({greetings: 'Dark Side'})
      this.setState({clickFor: 'Wookie'})
      this.setState({face: faceanni})
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrap">
        <div style={{marginTop: '2em', marginBottom: '5em', width: '80%'}}>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            <StarTitle>Coming soon!</StarTitle>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            <Row center="md">
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6}>
                <p>{this.state.greetings}</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>click for {this.state.clickFor}!</button>
                <img src={this.state.face} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)